# Loop not Inserting Values on to a Summary Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to compile one list from 300 worksheets that are identically formatted. I want to paste/insert the values on this summary sheet so that after each iteration of the loop, the new data is placed in the next empty row, so that there is one single "Master List". I'm getting a "type mismatch" error on the  "Summary.Cells" line, 4th from the bottom.

```
Sub Compile()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim Summary as Worksheet

Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If Not ws.Name = "Summary" Then

Summary.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row+1 = ws.Range("BB1:DO11").Value

End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks,

Comment: Try `Summary.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`. Plus what Scott said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is virtually the same as Scott's answer so if you are good enough to accept one, please accept his, but just shows a slightly different way of resizing the range.

```
Sub Compile()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Summary As Worksheet

Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then  'I think this is right but may need to be 'Summary'
        With ws.Range("BB1:DO11")
            Summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Pish... let the OP decide which they like better, personally your approach is easier to read and maintain, besides I already maxed out today.

Comment: @Scott Craner - ha, don't tell me there's a daily limit.

Comment: yup, I am not certain of all the rules but after 300 you can only get points for correct answers.  The upvotes just stop adding to your score for that day.

Comment: Ah ok. I doubt I will ever have that problem.

Comment: @ScottCraner ,SJR Thank you both very much. Its really helpful to have such a responsive and generous community to help out. I swear I feel like everytime I understand something, I hit a situation where it feels like I'm learning for the first time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

When assigning the values directly the ranges must be the same size.

You are trying to equate a row number to an array.

> `Summary.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row+1`

returns a row number as a Long not a Range.

To get the first cell we use, as per SJR's comment:

```
Summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Then we need to resize that to the same size as the input range.

```
Summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(11, 66).Value
```

use

```
Sub Compile()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Summary As Worksheet

Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'This does not match the skipped sheet name.

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not ws.Name = "Summary" Then 'Should this be "Sheet1" or Summary.Name
        Summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(11, 66).Value = ws.Range("BB1:DO11").Value
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```